# What is System.InvalidOperationException: Your fragment is not generic and it does not have MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute attribute set?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

On Xamarin.android\MvvmCross I'm getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Your fragment is not generic and it
>   does not have MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute attribute set!

This occurs on OnCreate method when I move my app to the background, change language on system settings and when I return to my app, it crashes with the above exception.

What does this mean, and what can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Does it work before you change the language? Have you try to reinstall the app?

Comment: @Billy Without changing the language everything is ok when I'm returning to the app which was in the background. And yes, I reinstalled the app.

Comment: Which line throws this exception? Could you post your code?

Comment: I am also facing this issue and it happen when I rotate screen while my dialogbox is open.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this error?

Comment: Did anyone get a fix for this?

Comment: If you just add this property to your Activity, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, it seems to solve the issue      @rideintothesun

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by your fragment being reconstructed, it needs to know the corresponding view model.

the fragment needs the MvxPresentationFragmentAttribute set

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(ViewModelType = typeof(YourViewModel))]
public class YourViewModelFragment : MvxFragment
{
....
}
```